Custom logger extension method
I'm building a MAUI app where I added MetroLog. I'm now trying to create a custom logging method which would be an extension for the ILogger.
public static class LoggerCustomExtensions
{
    public static void LogErrorAndNotifyUser(this ILogger logger, string? message, params object?[] args)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, message!, args!);
        ShowErrorMessage();
    }
}

Then the logger is injected into class constructors elsewhere in the code.
private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

Unfortunately, the method is not visible when I try to call it from the injected instance.
_logger.LogErrorAndNotifyUser("Failed to read items {0}. Error: {1}", ex.Message);

What am I doing wrong?

Is LoggerCustomExtensions in scope? (Missing "using ...." ?). Also: Is _logger declared as ILogger or ILogger<T> ?

Wait, is ShowErrorMessage() displaying an error on a UI? I'd strongly advise against doing that from the logger extension.

@Fildor, I have a using for the namespace where LoggerCustomExtensions is defined. Should I add a namespace somewhere else too? The _logger is declared as ILogger<MyClass> _logger

You need to import it where you use it. Otherwise the extension is not visible.

@Fildor, I have a using for the namespace where LoggerCustomExtensions is defined.

If it's in scope then your extension should be visible. Given ILogger and ILogger are from MS logging API abstractions, it should be good. So, there must be something else.

I'd just recommend to separate logging and UI interaction. But I don't think that's causing the immediate issue seen here.

Found the problem. The ILogger in the extension method was autoresolved as MetroLog.ILogger instead of the one from MS. I added the full qualifier this Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger and it works now (could also add using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;). I can see my method in _logger.
